# I can put in employee count and hours but then it prints out Rate >$pay is $ 0.00

Tags: c

Every time I run the code it asks me to insert in "Number of employees" "Hours" then automatically it will print out "Rate > $Pay is $ 0.00". Can someone help me? ** The input I am putting in my program is "Number of emplyees> 3" "hours> 50" but wouldn't let me insert the rate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double total_pay;
    int    count_emp;
    int    number_emp;
    double hours;
    double rate;
    double pay;

    printf("Enter number of employees> ");
    scanf("%d", &number_emp);
    
    total_pay = 0.0;
    count_emp = 0;      
    while (count_emp < number_emp) {
        printf("Hours> ") ;
        scanf("%1f", &hours);
        printf("Rate > $");
        scanf("%1f", &rate);
        pay = hours + rate;
        printf("Pay is $%6.2f\n\n", pay);
        total_pay = total_pay + pay;
        count_emp = count_emp + 1;
    }
    printf("All employees processed\n");
    printf("Total payroll is $%8.2f\n", total_pay);
    
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `hours + rate;` is the wrong formula. Should be hours * hourly rate.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for your help, I have changed it but the program still prints out "Rate > $Pay is $ 0.00" it wouldn't let me continue to insert the rate

Comment: Did you mean `%lf` instead of `%1f` in your `scanf` format strings? https://ideone.com/Hc2StL

Comment: since it's tagged with c, I'll assume it's c. When you printf, it will also count as something read by scanf so you need to clear your buffer with fflush() before you scanf, I think...idk it's been a while since I used c.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I honestly didn't pay attention to that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

> [I honestly didn't pay attention to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746319/i-can-put-in-employee-count-and-hours-but-then-it-prints-out-rate-pay-is-0-0/70746639#comment125068184_70746319)

That is where enabling all compile warnings saves time.  Enable them all.

Example:

> warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]

---

`1` vs. `l`

```
//      v-- digit 1: scan at most 1 character to form a float 
scanf("%1f", &hours);
scanf("%lf", &hours);
//      ^-- letter l: scan characters to form a double
```